# Ball always showing in Unity

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Some weird "ball" is showing when I select an element in Unity, preventing me to see the object itself:

[image: Weird ball 1]

I've tried to hide some layers, but even with all layers hidden it's still here:

[image: Weird ball 2]

Do you know how to hide this thing?
Any idea is greatly welcomed :)

Comment: That looks like the "vertices" you can drag around that are used in lightmaps. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to make them hidden, but thought it would help you find something relevant about it.

Comment: @TomTsagk I followed this idea, and found that it was actually *light probes*, and then that you can swtich them off in the gizmo menu. See answer below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @TomTsagk's comment on the question above, I've found it.

It was **light probes** that needed to be switched off, this is done in the **Gizmo menu** (in scene view):

[image: Light probes off]